# How to log MySQLi querys in a new table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

Using PHP5, with the MySQLi class for executing MySQL queries, how can I log each query processed using MySQLi::query in a new table in the currently connected database?

Is it possible to do some extension on the function, like in Java?

Comment: extend the class with your own `->myquery()` which does the logging then sends the query onto the real `->query()`?

Comment: I've not had experience in extending php classes, though it would be more convenient to extend the ->query().

Comment: Why not just enable the general query log on your MySQL server if you want this?

Comment: The script needs to be easily transferable from web server to web server, so enabling the general MySQL query log isn't an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use version of mysql that supports triggers. Just create a trigger, this way you will not have to pollute code with unnecessary business logic

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/triggers.html

Support for triggers is included beginning with MySQL 5.0.2. So when you deploy your app create triggers at the same time you create tables.

Answer (score 0):

Define a table for your logs

```
create table querylog (
tm timestamp,
query varchar(4096));
```

and when you do a query, log the query string in this table

```
insert into querylog (tm, query)
values(now(), '$query_string')
```

You can do this either explicit at every query or in a function `my_query`, you define and call instead of `mysqli_query` or, as @E_p suggested, in a trigger.